# Using OneNote API without registering an application?

Tags: onenote

The question is pretty clear I think, but I will elaborate on why I'm asking it.

I created a little blog engine based on OneNote. Basically, the blog configuration asks for an access to OneNote. Then the user chooses a section under which the blog posts are stored. 
There is a cron script that will use all these informations to automatically get new pages, fetch the medias and cache every, and finally display the posts.

I chose OneNote because I own three Windows 8 computers and a Windows Phone, so OneNote was an easy choice, as I didn't want to get an other application to manage my blog.

There is still *a lot* to do (as always with softwares...), but I want to make this more or less an open source project, so that other people can install it on their websites and link it directely to OneNote.

The only "big" obstacle for this now is that authentication in the OneNote API needs to register the application on the Live Connect, and specify a redirect domain. So every user wishing to use this blog engine on their server will have to register their own application... That will look complicated just for a blog, especially if you're not tech-savvy.

Is there a way to "skip" or work around this requirement, even if it requires the user to make the section public (as it is for a blog, this doesn't seem too much to ask) ?

Thank you in advance,

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an awesome project! When you get it released be sure to let us know at @OneNoteDev.

Unfortunately,  at this time there's no way to circumvent the requirement for Live Connect OAuth configuration. You could offer a hosted variant so only you need to worry about the LiveID configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is clear enough to make me abandon the idea to distribute the project, at least for now. But I'm still working on the project. It's not really production ready yet, but the hardest part is now done :)
I'll let you know as soon as it is advanced enough for me.

Again, thanks for the quick answer, it gives a really good impression of the team :)